# How to access document directly through ComsoDB stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, azure-cosmosdb

In my stored procedures I often have to access another document, and currently do a query e.g. `var query = 'SELECT * from foo f where f.id = "bar"';`

I know this will always return 1 result, so is there a way I can access the document directly by id without having to do a query?

Comment: Hi,any updates now?

Answer (score 0):

You can call a document directly through the REST API with the following URL when using SQL(Core):

> https://{databaseaccount}.documents.azure.com/dbs/{db-id}/colls/{coll-id}/docs/{doc-id}

More information about this interface can be found here: [Get a Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/get-a-document)

Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

> I know this will always return 1 result, so is there a way I can
>   access the document directly by id without having to do a query?

Per my knowledge, there is no such method to get document directly without doing a query in stored procedure.

If you want to access the document which is fixed, you could fully pass it into the stored procedure as a `json string parameter`, without doing a redundant query.

If the accessed document is flexible, you need to query by it's `id` or it's `_self` property.